# The relationship between Stirling number of the second kind and the polylogarithm

Tags: special-functions, generating-functions, reference-request

It is shown here on [Mathworld's page on Stirling number of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html) that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k) (k-1)! z^k = (-1)^n \text{Li}_{1-n}(1+\frac{1}{z})
$$

where $S(n,k)$ is Stirling number of the second kind and $\text{Li}_{1-n}$ is the polylogarithm.

Can somebody provide me some reference on where this identity came from? It isn't shown on Mathworld's page.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, this seems to simply the result of a Lagrange inversion of a series for the polylog function (see the Wikipedia page for the series for Li that is a candidate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Steven Landsburg's note.](http://www.thebigquestions.com/dotcom/query.pdf)